# Suggestions: Perfectionist Badge - Dialectical badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request, captcha

I suggest adding an *Perfectionist badge* for people who, due to their frequent edits on their own answers or comments, have run through the captcha system 30+ times. This should encourage people to reformulate their own words when they think they can improve even slightly their answers, and to find appropriate words.

I also would suggest the *dialectical badge* for people who have made 5+ answers that extend over 2 KiloBytes without counting code segments (maybe hard to implement because some don't know how to format their code). This denotes the willing of being precise and pedagogical.

Comment: First question for badge request: *What is the positive behavior the requested badge is supposed to encourage?*

Comment: As I'm diagnosed with ADD, I'm feeling discriminated by the hyperactive badge.

Comment: @balpha, +1 from me. I can see the positive behaviour for the "dialectical badge" (as I've outlined below) but I'm not so sure on the "hyperactive badge".. Stopping and thinking, rather than hitting the captcha repeatedly would seem to me to be a more desirable outcome! =)

Comment: Hello Gamecat. As I am not a native English speaker I could not find a better wording for the first proposal. I did not mean to offend anyone. I relied only on etymology, hyperactive having a meaning of “who acts more than the average person” and felt it in a positive way. I would be glad if you could suggest some other term for that (I had thought of “semi-robot”, “never auto-satisfied”).

Comment: @Benoit, possibly "Perfectionist" would be an appropriate choice of word =)

Comment: @Rob: thank you, I really like it. I renamed from Hyperactive to Perfectionist.

Answer (score 2):

> First question for bage request: What
>   is the positive behavior the requested
>   badge is supposed to encourage?

I can see the merit of the "dialectical badge" more than the "hyperactive badge" in that context, although I'm not sure precisely where the "length" value for triggering the badge could/should be set. Take the following as a hypothetical situation:

## Q

I'm writing a C# winforms app and want to flash the titlebar/taskbar button like Messenger does

## A1

Use the [FlashWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679347%28VS.85%29.aspx) Win32 API call to achieve this.

## A2

Use the [FlashWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679347%28VS.85%29.aspx) Win32 API call to achieve this. You'll need to use [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) to call out to Windows as it's not a native function available in the .net framework BCL.

To use this you'll need to define a `struct` that the API call uses, as well as the signature of the API call. They are (taken from [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FlashWindowEx.html)):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool FlashWindowEx(ref FLASHWINFO pwfi);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct FLASHWINFO
{
    public UInt32 cbSize;
    public IntPtr hwnd;
    public UInt32 dwFlags;
    public UInt32 uCount;
    public UInt32 dwTimeout;
}
```

You can then call the API to cause the window to flash, like this:

```
// This code would be a method on the window you want to "flash", taken from
// http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2008/04/19/3392.aspx
public static bool Flash()
{
    FLASHWINFO fw = new FLASHWINFO();

    fw.cbSize = Convert.ToUInt32(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(FLASHWINFO)));
    fw.hwnd = this.Handle;
    fw.dwFlags = 2;
    fw.uCount = UInt32.MaxValue;

    FlashWindowEx(ref fw);
}
```

---

Whilst the second answer is *essentially* the same as the first, but quoting sections of the linked articles it does achieve the desired (in my mind at least) outcome of making the answer on stackoverflow truly comprehensive and the "one-stop shop" to answer that particular question with additional reading provided, should the OP of the question need it.

It's likely that the second answer would receive sufficient up-votes to receive a "Nice Answer", or better, badge which would somewhat reduce the need/purpose of a "Long Answer" badge so, perhaps the badge proposal could be transmuted from that to "Comprehensive Answer":

- Has at least n% of the up-votes for answers on the question
- Is at least n% of the total size of the answers on the question
- Contains at least n links
- Contains at least n code-blocks

I'm not too sure on the last two requirements, but as I've generally found that code examples and "further reading" tend to enhance an answer I've dropped them in there.

Comment: "I am writing you a long letter, since I lack the time to make it a short one." - Pascal???  Descartes???